# Moving an HTML element without an element id in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to move an HTML element to a location "after" the indicated element id

```
<div class="some">
  <div id="dest">blablabla</div>
</div>

<div id="source">
  test
</div>
```

I want to move the div "source" after "dest":

```
<div class="some">
  <div id="dest">blablabla</div>
  <div id="source">
     test
  </div>
</div>
```

The parent of "dest" doesn't have an ID!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`ChildNode.after()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/after) for that

> The ChildNode.after() method inserts a set of Node or DOMString objects in the children list of this ChildNode's parent, just after this ChildNode. DOMString objects are inserted as equivalent Text nodes.

```js
function move() {
  let dest = document.getElementById("dest");
  let source = document.getElementById("source");

  dest.after(source);
}
```

```html
<div class="some">
  <div id="dest">blablabla</div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="move" onclick="move()">
<div id="source">
  test
</div>
```